# Small exercise for Java given two arrays which represents a path

Tags: java, arrays, loops, recursion

Given two arrays which represents a path and each element in the array represent the time it takes the driver to travel, write a method that chooses the fastest path he can take. The driver can switch paths only once between arrays.
For example the following arrays:

```
int[] road1 = new int[] { 5, 4, 5, 8, 12, 9, 9, 3 };
int[] road2 = new int[] { 7, 3, 3, 12, 10, 2, 10, 7 };
```

the output should be 49 since the driver will start at road2 and switch at index 6 to the second Array.

Edit:
My question is how do I make the recursion stop after switching to the other array? I tried to put a counter marker but it didn't work and I reverted back to my original output. Am I missing something about how recursion works?

My code prints 53 where it should print 49.

My code:

```
public class MyClass {

    public static int shortestRoad(int[] road1, int[] road2) {
        return shortestRoadNumbers(road1, road2, 0);
    }

    private static int shortestRoadNumbers(int[] road1, int[] road2, int index) {
        if (index == road1.length || index == road2.length) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (road1[index] >= road2[index] && road1[index + 2] >= road2[index + 2]) {
            return (road2[index] + shortestRoadNumbers(road1, road2, index + 1));
        } else {
            return (road1[index] + shortestRoadNumbers(road1, road2, index + 1));
        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[] road1 = new int[] { 5, 4, 5, 8, 12, 9, 9, 3 };
        int[] road2 = new int[] { 7, 3, 3, 12, 10, 2, 10, 7 };
        MyClass.shortestRoad(road1, road2);
        int result = MyClass.shortestRoad(road1, road2);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Several issues : There is no question. You do not provide the output of your trying. StakOverflow is not a place where you ask other people do your homework.

Comment: Ask your self: Do your code meet the requirement that _"The driver can switch paths only once between arrays."_?

Comment: Debug your application and see why it's not behaving as you want it.

Comment: Also please read [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: You ask *My question is how do I make the recursion stop after switching to the other array?* The answer: Don’t use recursion. This can be solved using only 1 pass over the arrays. It’s your job to figure out how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the following schema to illustrate your problem
[image]

We have two paths, and each path contain many nodes (values) , we can switch from one path to another just one time. Find the best combination of nodes (values) that minimise the score.
We can distinguish 4 cases:
1- the sum of the values of the first path without switching.
2-the sum of the values of the second path without switching.
3-the sum of the values from the first path until a node i, then switch to path second path from node i+1 (sum from node+1 til the end)
4-the inverse of the point 3.

```
static int shortestRoad(int road1[], int road2[])
{
    // case 1
    int bestValue = sumValues(road1,0);

    // case 2
    int sumValuesRoad2 = sumValues(road2,0);
    if ( sumValuesRoad2 < bestValue)
        bestValue = sumValuesRoad2;

    // case 3: best values of all combination from road 1 to road 2
    int bestValuesSwitchFromRoad1ToRoad2 = shortestRoad_Switch_RoadFrom_RoadTo(road1, road2);
    if ( bestValuesSwitchFromRoad1ToRoad2 < bestValue)
        bestValue = bestValuesSwitchFromRoad1ToRoad2;

    // case 4: best values of all combination from road 2 to road 1
    int bestValuesSwitchFromRoad2ToRoad1 =  shortestRoad_Switch_RoadFrom_RoadTo(road2, road1);

    if ( bestValuesSwitchFromRoad2ToRoad1 < bestValue)
        bestValue = bestValuesSwitchFromRoad2ToRoad1;

    return bestValue;
}
```

sum the values of a given array from idx til the end:

```
static int sumValues(int array[], int idx_from)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = idx_from; i<array.length; ++i)
        sum += array[i];

    return sum;
}
```

case 3 and 4:

```
static int shortestRoad_Switch_RoadFrom_RoadTo(int[] road_from, int[] road_to)
{
    int sumValues_RoadFrom_til_idx = 0;
    int sumValues_RoadFrom_idx_switch_RoadTo = 0;
    int bestValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    for (int i = 0; i<road_from.length-1; ++i)
    {
        sumValues_RoadFrom_til_idx += road_from[i];

        sumValues_RoadFrom_idx_switch_RoadTo = sumValues_RoadFrom_til_idx+sumValues(road_to,i+1);

        if(sumValues_RoadFrom_idx_switch_RoadTo < bestValue )
            bestValue = sumValues_RoadFrom_idx_switch_RoadTo;
    }

    return bestValue;
}
```

Driver code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    
    int road1[] = { 5, 4, 5, 8, 12, 9, 9, 3 };
    int road2[] = { 7, 3, 3, 12, 10, 2, 10, 7 };

    int road_a[] = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 9, 9, 9,9,9 };
    int road_b[] = { 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 1, 1, 1,1,1 };

    int road_c[] = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2 };
    int road_d[] = { 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 1, 1, 1,1,1 };

    System.out.println("best road1, road2 = "+shortestRoad(road1,road2));
    System.out.println("best road_a, road_b = "+shortestRoad(road_a,road_b));
    System.out.println("best road_c, road_d = "+shortestRoad(road_c,road_d));

    return 0;
}
```

Results:

```
best road1, road2 = 49
best road_a, road_b = 10
best road_c, road_d = 7
```

ps:
the best path in your example is begin from road2 and then switch to road 1 at i=5 (i begin from 0)

```
{    5, 4, 5, 8, 12, 9,  -->9, 3 }  
{ -->7, 3, 3, 12, 10, 2 /, 10, 7 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int shortestRoad(int[]road1, int[]road2)
{
  int sumRoad1Only = 0;
  int sumRoad2Only = 0;
  for(int i=0; i<road1.length; i++)
  {
    sumRoad1Only += road1[i];
    sumRoad2Only += road2[i];
  }
```

Those sums are for the option that the driver chooses one lane, and doesn't change it until the end. Now, we can find the switch index, for options like starting at one road, and switching to the other. In this specific question I realized that the best point of switch between the arrays - is where the difference between the two collected sums until a certain index is the largest. In your example, it is index 6. That doesn't say that switching a lane is always giving a smaller sum.

```
int roadIndex1 = road1.length-1;
int roadIndex2 = road2.length-1;
int totalSumRoad1 = sumRoad1Only;
int totalSumRoad2 = sumRoad2Only;

int max = 0;
int indexOfSwitch = 0;
int diff = 0;

while(roadIndex1 >=0 && roadIndex2 >=0)
{
  diff = Math.abs(totalSumRoad2 - totalSumRoad1);
  if(diff > max)
  {
    max = diff;
    indexOfSwitch = roadIndex1;
  }
  totalSumRoad1 -= road1[roadIndex1];
  totalSumRoad2 -= road2[roadIndex2];
  roadIndex1--;
  roadIndex2--;
}
```

If the index of switch is at last index, we shall move it one left, so there be a transition between the arrays.

```
if(indexOfSwitch == road1.length-1)
{
  indexOfSwitch--;
}
```

now we found the indexOfSwitch, we can calculate the options of starting at road1, and switching exactly once to road2, and vice versa:

```
int begin1 = 0;
int begin2 = 0;
for(int k = 0; k<=indexOfSwitch; k++)
{
  begin1 += road1[k];
  begin2 += road2[k];
}

int end1 = sumRoad1Only - begin1;
int end2 = sumRoad2Only - begin2;

int begin1End2 = begin1 + end2;
int begin2End1 = begin2 + end1;
```

and when we find all the options, we can return the minimum.

```
return Math.min(Math.min(sumRoad1Only, sumRoad2Only), Math.min(begin1End2, begin2End1));
```